# How do you create a sequence using Sqlalchemy and add that particular sequence to a table?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

```
rollback.py :

def write_to_db(dataset_id):
    try:
        initialize_datamodels()
        EpdUmpPushRollback = datamodels.relational_tables.EpdUmpPushRollback
        with session_scope() as session:
            epdumppushrollback_obj = EpdUmpPushRollback()
            epdumppushrollback_obj.dataset_id = dataset_id
            epdumppushrollback_obj.record_id = ''
            epdumppushrollback_obj.operator_name = 'vis'
            epdumppushrollback_obj.activation_flag = 'active'
            epdumppushrollback_obj.record_creation_time = now()
            epdumppushrollback_obj.start_time = now()
            session.add(epdumppushrollback_obj)
            session.flush()

    except Exception as e:
        #err = "Error in updating the table epd_ump_push_rollback "
        #_log.exception(err)
        _log.exception("Error in updating the table {}".format(e))

table.py :

"""epd_ump_push_rollback_table

Revision ID: 4e4d99a8e544
Revises: c010f4d4b319
Create Date: 2018-12-19 18:04:30.271380

"""
from alembic import op
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, INTEGER, VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, TIMESTAMP, \
    Enum, ForeignKey, Sequence, MetaData

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '4e4d99a8e544'
down_revision = '2396e1b7de5c'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

meta = MetaData()
seq_obj = Sequence('record_id_seq', metadata=meta)


def upgrade():
    activation_flag_state = Enum('active', 'inactive', name="activation_flag_state")

    op.create_table('epd_ump_push_rollback',
                    Column('dataset_id', String, ForeignKey('epd_ip_dataset.dataset_id'),
                           primary_key=True),
                    Column('record_id', INTEGER, seq_obj, server_default=seq_obj.next_value(),
                           primary_key=True),
                    Column('operator_name', String, nullable=False),
                    Column('activation_flag', activation_flag_state, nullable=False),
                    Column('record_creation_time', TIMESTAMP),
                    Column('start_time', TIMESTAMP),
                    Column('end_time', TIMESTAMP))


def downgrade():
    op.drop_table('epd_ump_push_rollback')
    op.execute('DROP type activation_flag_state')
```

Explanation:

In the `rollback.py` file I am writing into db. I am setting a session with `db(postgresql)` using `with session_scope() as session:`. I am creating a object of table `EpdUmpPushRollback` and setting those values appropriately. The column `record_id` should be generated as sequence which I am defining in `table.py` and I am using alembic to upgrade my schema to new one which will have the table `EpdUmpPushRollback`.

I have two questions now.

1. For the column where we have defined sequence, is it mandatory to add using `pdumppushrollback_obj.record_id = ''` or it gets added automatically?
2. What should be the name of the sequence, whenever I try to add any entry in the table, it throws this error.

> Error:  sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError)
>   "record_id_seq" is not a sequence [SQL: 'INSERT INTO
>   epd_ump_push_rollback (dataset_id, operator_name, activation_flag,
>   record_creation_time, start_time, end_time) VALUES (%(dataset_id)s,
>   %(operator_name)s, %(activation_flag)s, now(), now(), %(end_time)s)
>   RETURNING epd_ump_push_rollback.record_id'] [parameters:
>   {'dataset_id': '20181221_1200_mno', 'operator_name': 'vis',
>   'activation_flag': 'active', 'end_time': None}]

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
seq_obj = Sequence('record_id_seq', metadata=meta)
```

is not enough.
You need to add, in `upgrade()`, above the table creation:

```
op.execute(schema.CreateSequence(seq_obj))
```

Also, drop sequence is needed in `downgrade()` function

Answer (score 1):

I already had this problem once and to solve it I created the sequence, so you can try this postgres statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE record_id_seq
   START WITH 1
   INCREMENT BY 1
   NO MINVALUE
   NO MAXVALUE
   CACHE 1;
```